# Phpmailer,SMTP,Gmail seetings and connection

Tags: smtp, connection, gmail, phpmailer

I'm doing a project which sends mail. I have downloaded phpmailer.
I'm using SMTP and all code for connecting to Gmail was very fine. And also i turned Gmail 2step verification.and allowed low secured apps. I'm still getting "failed to connect"
When i specified ssl the error is on line 294 in PHPMailerAutoload.php which referring socket parameters.
 I hope anyone can help me with this connection problem and if any Gmail settings needed.

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

actually im using PHPMailer to send mails.and downloaded everything neede for it.
 Everytime when i execute i got the faallowing error
"stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:" and so on.
Later on i found the solution in this link
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/368

## then i added this

$mail->smtpConnect(
    array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
            "allow_self_signed" => true

## )));

code in my mail sending php file and finally it worked..
hope you undestand... :)